# Crash during guided resize installation of 16.04.4 LTS from USB Flash drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am pretty new to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and I ran into a problem during its installation.

I am on an asus zenbook and therefore there is no dvd reader. I created a USB flash drive with rufus and all seemed to work perfectly. I managed to get to the installation (alongside Windows) but just after the guided resize (when I have to choose how much place I give to Ubuntu) there is a splash with quite a long detail from which the most significant sentence is:

> ubiquity crashed with valueError in translate_to_c(): Guided-resize SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #5 (sda) and use freedspace

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't explain what the precise cause of the error is, it is probably related to not enough free space or some sort of "bad" partitioning.

You could try manual partitioning (there are guides for that) or just erase the drive completely. The latter definitely "resolves" the issue.